# Фильтрация по дате (атрибуту datetime)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой вопрос. Как сделать для данного примера фильтр по атрибуту datetime?

Чтоб я мог например выбрать месяц November в теге select и мне покажет за этот месяц посты.

Я начинающий в js и jquery. И с подобным никогда не сталкивался. Толкового решения найти не могу.

Возможно тут кто-то знает. Буду очень благодарен за решение и опыт на будущее.

И возможно ли такое? Или как сделать лучше?

```css
.container {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.post-list {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.post-item {
 flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: black;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
margin: 0;
}

p:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-filter">
  <div class="filter-block">
    <select class="filter-months">
      <option>November</option>
      <option>October</option>
      <option>March</option>
      <option>January</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="post-list">
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 1</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-11-01T13:29:31+00:00">November 1, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 2</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-10-04T11:27:22+00:00">October 4, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 3</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-03-21T15:52:31+00:00">March 21, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-01-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А где у вас разметка для фильтра по месяцам?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, у меня задача сделать это через тег select. Я в таком слаб, не знаю как такое реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите пример.

Что здесь можно улучшить:

- Дату (datetime) перенести на `.post-item`.
- Добавить анимацию появления\скрытия.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.filter-months');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filterByMonth(select.value);
});
filterByMonth(select.value);

function filterByMonth(month) {
  const valMonth = +month;
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.post-list .post-item');
  [...items].forEach((el) => {
    const attr = el.querySelector('.post-date').getAttribute('datetime');
    const date = new Date(attr);
    if (date.getMonth() === valMonth) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.post-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.post-item {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.post-item.hidden {
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-filter">
  <div class="filter-block">
    <select class="filter-months">
      <option value='10' selected>November</option>
      <option value='9'>October</option>
      <option value='2'>March</option>
      <option value='0'>January</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="post-list">
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 1</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-11-01T13:29:31+00:00">November 1, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 2</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-10-04T11:27:22+00:00">October 4, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 3</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-03-21T15:52:31+00:00">March 21, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-01-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение! Отметил ваш ответ)

Comment: и такой еще вопрос, а какое значение нужно вставить в option чтоб оно показывало всё?

Comment: @СтаниславКремса В данном варианте - никакое. Надо править код. Надеюсь, сами сможете поправить. Даже более того, я вам настойчиво рекомендую сделать это самому.

Comment: да, получилось) Переписал условие: if (date.getMonth() === valMonth || valMonth == 12 )

Comment: Подставляю по логике просто слово year чтоб сделать фильтр для годов но оно не работает. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: получилось на года тоже)

Comment: @СтаниславКремса вы молодец! Только valMonth лучше все же не `12` делать, а например `null`, `undefined` или пустой строкой.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую! Я создал еще один вопрос. Как сделать чтоб эти два фильтра работали сообща?

Comment: @СтаниславКремса даю подсказку. Функция фильтрации должна быть одна, но принимать два параметра - год и месяц. И условие соответствующее прописать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно не прописывать value в select а вычислить в скрипте. Эффект "slow" можно удалить.

```js
$('p.post-date').each(function () { 
    month=$(this).attr('datetime').split("-")[1];
    $(this).attr('filter',month);
});

$('select.filter-months').on('change', function() {
  $('p.post-date').parent().hide('slow');
  $('p.post-date[filter='+$(this).val()+']').parent().show('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-filter">
  <div class="filter-block">
    <select class="filter-months">
      <option value=11>November</option>
      <option value=10>October</option>
      <option value=03>March</option>
      <option value=01>January</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="post-list">
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 1</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-11-01T13:29:31+00:00">November 1, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 2</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-10-04T11:27:22+00:00">October 4, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 3</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-03-21T15:52:31+00:00">March 21, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-01-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```